Has anyone tried growing pansies in Zone 13b tropics?
Basically, I'm trying to grow pansies in zone 13b. I purchased seeds from a farmers markets, however nearly everyone I referred to said they're for zones 4-8. Also, the germination temperature is around 11-17°C which is hard to achieve here, but some winters do tinker within these ranges. Will they grow here? Cultivar:- Pansy Swiss Giant .

Can you concoct any shady coolness? Indoors in your AC? In the tropics, I'd grow pansy-faced Miltonia orchids. They, too, will not like it over 32C/90F.

@YosefBaskin that seems like a good idea. But not efficient in long term, our home recieves natural ventilation, it's not exactly humid per se but rather we oftentimes have hot breezes. How did you compensate the temperature for Milltonias?

I have a Miltonia in bloom now outside facing south, but they too like cool and bright. In New Jersey, more sun means more heat, a challenge. November - April, they're inside at a South window.

I appreciate your insights. Thanks a lot. @YosefBaskin
